# How to make blank the null data while exporting to Excel

Tags: c#

I have a column date in my datagridview, and I want it to display it in Excel to 12 hours, because it is 24 hours (sample: 16/06/19  7:00 PM). This problem is fine, I solved it, but the real problem is if I have data is null, it displays like this (16/06/19  12:00 AM). It always has time value 12:00 AM, I just want to display only the date, like this (16/06/19 ). I need a condition for this, but I don't know how.

This is my code for exporting to excel:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = 
app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";

for (int i = 1; i < dataGridViewIn.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridViewIn.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewIn.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    (worksheet.Rows[i + 2 + ":" + i + 2, System.Reflection.Missing.Value] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).NumberFormat = "@";
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewIn.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridViewIn.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].NumberFormat = " m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM";
    }
}
      
var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialoge.FileName = "TimeIn";
saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    app.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want 12-hour clock use small `hh` , You want the 24-hour clock use capital `HH`

```
if (dateTime == null)
{
    DateTime date=Covert.ToDateTime( lastdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

use `tt` in the format string to produce the AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach (datagridview rw in this.datagridview1.rows){
    For (int i=1 ; i<rw.cells.count ; i++){
        if (rw.cells[i]. value == null){
            rw.cells[i]. value = "*";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.